# how does set Simple Column work in iText landscape pdf

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to write Arabic text into PDF using iText 
I have implemented the Arabic example and it worked on a vertical paper not landscape

[image: output of pdf]

First it did not show any letters then I switched the numbers and the text appeared on top of each other like a column.
These are the parameters of `setSimpleColumn(llx,lly,urx,ury)` but which is which and how does it work?

code

```
public static final String FONT = "C:/Users/Hanoofi/Documents/projects/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf";
public static final String DEST = "C:/Users/Hanoofi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/quranGrades";
public static final String Sentence1 = "\u0627\u0644\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a \u0623\u0639\u0632 \u0645\u0646 \u062a\u0645\u0633\u0643 \u0628\u0643\u062a\u0627\u0628\u0647 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0635\u0644\u0627\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0631\u0633\u0648\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0626\u0644\u003a \u0028\u062e\u064a\u0631\u0643\u0645 \u0645\u0646 \u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0631\u0622\u0646 \u0648 \u0639\u0644\u0645\u0647\u0029 \u0648\u0628\u0639\u062f\u003a \u062a\u0634\u0647\u062f \u0625\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0645\u062f\u0631\u0633\u0629 ";
public static final String Sentence2 = "\u0634\u0647\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u062a\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0631";
public static final String Sentence3 = "\u0634\u0647\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u062a\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0631";
public static final String Sentence4 = "\u0634\u0647\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u062a\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0631";
public static final String Sentence5 = "\u0634\u0647\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u062a\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0631";
public static final String Sentence6 = "\u0634\u0647\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u062a\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0631";


public void ArabicExample() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
  Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, 
          new FileOutputStream("Ara.pdf"));
  document.open();
  Font f = FontFactory.getFont(FONT,BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
  Phrase p = new Phrase(new Chunk(Sentence1,f)) ;

  ColumnText canvas = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
 // canvas.setSimpleColumn(36, 750, 559, 780);
  canvas.setSimpleColumn(750,36,780,559);

  canvas.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
  canvas.addElement(p);
  canvas.go();

  document.close();

}
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with an old version of iText is much easier to achieve with the most recent version of iText (that is version 7.1). Why don't you give the most recent version a try?

Comment: I am a beginner so itext 5 was where I found YouTube videos explaining it , I will try it with version 7